# On what site I can use to send ideas to Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I wonder is there a site that I can send to a company to add in Stack Exchange new things? Because I'd like to send few ideas to Stack Exchange for next update. If it is not good place can to tell me in what site from Stack Exchange I can ask this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Stack Exchange to implement a new feature, the best option is to ask a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) question on either a per-site meta (if it's a feature that's mostly only relevant to that one community) or on the network-wide [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) (if it's likely to be significant for people across multiple communities).

Stack Exchange is very much driven under the philosophy of community engagement: Whether or not Stack Exchange pays attention to your idea really depends on how well received it is by the respective communities.

Comment: So by going to feature-request then I can send my ideas to Stack Exchange for next update?

Comment: @AlexA feature-request is a tag you may use on a special StackExchange Meta site (like our site for Islam) or on Meta Stack Exchange (for general purpose in the Stack Exchaneg network)

Comment: @AlexA **<comments deleted>** Please refrain from using comments unless they're directly relevant to this post; comments are not a private messaging service nor are they a chat system. Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving *this post* as it pertains to the question asked.